# Including vendors / points of interest on Google Maps indoor floorplans

Tags: java, android, google-maps

How does google label points of interest (POI) for indoor floorplans in their native app (image attached)? I am trying to implement this functionality in an android app using google maps v2.
Note that if you change the floor level, the POI's are updated as well.

Currently, I am able to view the floorplan in my app, but without the POI labels. I was thinking the Google Places API would do the trick, but that just returns places in the surrounding area. Not the vendors within the mall. And correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't believe the Places API returns which floor the place would be located on. So that doesn't explain how Google updates the POI's when the floor level is changed.

Any help/insight on Google's implementation and how it can be replicated would be appreciated.

[image: map of mall with points of interest labeled]

Comment: Google doesn't have to provide all the data they have via Places API, don't you think?

Comment: They definitely don't have to, and I am most prepared for that answer. I'm simply looking for some confirmation as to whether or not this data is accessible to the "public".